# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource in

Tags: php, sql-server, crud

I'm having trouble displaying SQL Server 2016 database parameters, the problem is in this line:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
```

Query:

```
$query = "SELECT Nome, Pais, Estado FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE Nome = ? LIMIT 0,1";
```

Database:

```
<?php $host = "XXX"; $user = "XXX"; $password = "XXX"; $database = "XXX"; $conn = array("Database" => $database, "UID" => $user, "PWD" => $password); $con = sqlsrv_connect($host, $conn); if( !$con ) { print 'Connection could not be established.'; die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please check `errno` and `error` for `$con`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
$query = "SELECT Nome, Pais, Estado FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE Nome = ? LIMIT 0,1";
```

isn't going to work on SQL Server. LIMIT is a MySQL (and others) operator. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Nome, Pais, Estado FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE Nome = ? ORDER BY Nome OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY";
```